# Fiddler 4.6 cannot connect to strong SSL?

Tags: fiddler

Error:

```
[Fiddler] The connection to '<the site>.com' failed. 
System.Security.SecurityException Failed to negotiate HTTPS connection with server.fiddler.network.https> HTTPS handshake to <the site>.com (for #3) failed. System.IO.IOException Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. < An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

I can hit  fine in web browser. I do see it is rather strong SSL (FireFox reports it as TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, 256 bit keys, TLS 1.2)

Why isn't Fiddler able to make this connection?

Answer (score 114, accepted):

Seems that your client didn't try to connect via 1.2

Check: Tools > Fiddler Options > HTTPS
It's set to **<client>;ssl3;tls1.0**

Add "**tls1.2**" to the protocols list

**Edit:**
Refer to the image below for where to find the option:
[image]

Comment: I don't see those options in that place in fiddler.

Comment: In Fiddler 4 the option exists.

look at this screenshot
https://jackstromberg.com/2016/08/tutorial-using-fiddler-to-debug-saml-tokens-issued-from-adfs/fiddler-tools-telerik-fiddler-options-https-decrypt-https-traffic/

Comment: it worked me, use this screen shot. https://jackstromberg.com/2016/08/tutorial-using-fiddler-to-debug-saml-tokens-issued-from-adfs/fiddler-tools-telerik-fiddler-options-https-decrypt-https-traffic/

Comment: I suggested an edit. This error happens to me when I have ssl2 set in the same place.

Comment: In `Fiddler4` it's `Tools > Options`. And the option to add a `Protocol` only becomes visible if you check `Decrypt HTTPS traffic`, after which you can click `No`, go and add the `Protocol`s needed and then uncheck the `Decrypt HTTPS traffic` option.

Comment: Thanks @Neroon I wasted 6 hrs trying to fix this issue. Your response helped me .. I was loosing my mind... Thanks again.

Comment: This solution works also on below similar cases (slightly different error message).
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

[Fiddler] The connection to '<the site>' failed.  <br />System.Security.SecurityException Failed to negotiate HTTPS connection with server.fiddler.network.https&gt; HTTPS handshake to <the site> (for #123) failed. System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception The client and server cannot communicate, because they do not possess a common algorithm